# Flash image zoom with slider/scrollbar

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, zooming

I am trying to add a scrollbar, or prefrably a slider, that zooms in on the specified image when I drag the scrollbar right, and decreases the size when I drag the scrollbar to the left.

Here is my code thus far,

AS3:

```
mc_img.mask = mc_oval;
mc_img.buttonMode = true;

mc_img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dF);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropF);

function dF(event:MouseEvent):void {
    mc_img.startDrag();
}

function dropF(event:MouseEvent):void {
    mc_img.stopDrag();
}
```

so basically I would like to be able to zoom `mc_img` with a slider or scrollbar, so any links or tutorials, even some code snippets will be a great help!

Also please excuse my ignorance on the subject, I am new to Actionscript 3.

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `startDrag()` method have a `Rectangle` parameter.
You ca use it to limit the motion of the "slider".

```
mySliderGrip.startDrag(false, new Rectangle(0, 50, 100, 50));
```

This will lock the slider between 0 and 100 px horizontally, and 50px vertically.
The `false` parameter is a "Lock" to center at the mouse.

Now you can use the x position of the slider to get a percentage.
You can use it to do an scaleX and scaleY on the image.